# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' в name = item.find('b').text

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

При парсинге сайта начало выбивать ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alibPars\main.py", line 32, in <module>
name = item.find('b').text
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Код:

```
for page in booksPage:
soup = get_soup(page)
book = soup.find_all('p')
count = 0
for item in book:
    count += 1
    if 4 <= count <= 63:
        name = item.find('b').text
```

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас `item.find('b')` None

Answer (score 2):

В первую очередь, что-то не так с отступами в вашем коде. Потому я буду предполагать, что ваш оригинальный код такой:

```
for page in booksPage:
    soup = get_soup(page)
    book = soup.find_all('p')
    count = 0
    for item in book:
        count += 1
        if 4 <= count <= 63:
            name = item.find('b').text
```

Я его сделаю чуть красивее (и короче):

```
for page in booksPage:
    soup = get_soup(page)
    book = soup('p')                      # да, это работает («синтаксический сахар»)
    for item in book[3:63]:
        name = item.find('b').text
```

---

Теперь к вашей проблеме:

Что-то случилось не так, как вы полагали. Для какого-то `item` из вашего диапазона не существует тег `<b>`, значит, `item.find('b')` будет иметь значение `None`.

Чтобы предотвратить ошибку из-за того, *включите тест,* учитывая такую возможность:

```
for page in booksPage:
    soup = get_soup(page)
    book = soup('p')                      # да, это работает («синтаксический сахар»)
    for item in book[3:63]:
        found = item.find('b')            # сначала без .text; только ищем
        if found:                         # только для найденных
            name = found.text
```